What is the best way to reliably share internet to RPi zero from a windows machine over USB Ethernet/ RNDIS gadget Mode?
I have a headless setup for a Raspberry Pi zero. Connected over USB Ethernet/ RNDIS gadget.
My Windows PC internet connection is shared to the RPi over the USB cable as well.
My RPi does get the internet connection. However sometimes it doesn't get the connection if it is idle or I restart my PC.
I typically go to network connection, then unshare my PC internet, wait like 30 sec. And again reshare my connection and reboot the RPi. Then RPi does get the internet connection again.
Can anybody tell me How I can make the connection more reliable?
